# Ngrx store dispatch is not accepting string as arguments

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm taking a test in which I should write code a in such a way that all unit test case gets passed.

Case 1:

```
  it('should dispatch action when dispatchAction is called', async() => {
    // you need to spy on store's 'dispatch' method
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();

    // if you call function dispatchAction with 'movies' paramter. expect store to dispatch action='movies'
    component.dispatchAction('movies');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('movies');
  });
```

My code:

```
  dispatchAction($event: string) {
    this.store.dispatch({type: 'movie'});
  }
```

But the spec is getting failed throwing the below error

```
Expected spy dispatch to have been called with [ 'movies' ] but actual calls were [ Object({ type: 'movies' }) ].
```

**Reducer,**

```
export function news (state = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_SECTION_NEWS: {
            return {
                newsList: mockNewsList,
                filter: action.type
            };
        }
        case FILTER_SUBSECTION: {
            return {
                newsList: mockNewsList,
                filter: action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const getNewsList = (state: any) => {
    return state;
};

export const getFilter = (state: any) => {
    return state;
};
```

**Action**

```
export class NewsActions {
    static LOAD_SECTION_NEWS = '[News] LOAD_SECTION_NEWS';
    static FILTER_SUBSECTION = '[News] FILTER_SUBSECTION';

    LoadSectionNews(list: News[]): Action {
        return {
            type: '',
            payload: ''
        };
    }
    FilterSubsection(subsection: string) {
        return {
            type: '',
            payload: ''
        };
    }
}
```

How do I modify, the reducer in such a way that the unit test case get passed.

This Ngrx is out of syllabus and I've no idea. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The error reported is about `.toHaveBeenCalledWith('movies');` from your test case. The expectation is the word `movies` to have been used as argument, and this is incorrect.

When you call `this.store.dispatch({type: 'movies'});` in your controller, it is passing the object `{type: 'movies'}` as argument.

as your test is expecting only the word `movie`, it fails

change your expectation to

```
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({type: 'movies'});
```

that will fix your test

Good luck with your studies

Comment: I've updated my question. How do I updated the reducer function to accept only movie params ?

Comment: fyi, `this.store.dispatch('movies');` is not correct in ngrx - it expects an object with a `type` property

Comment: but is der anyother way of doing it ? I just wanted to pass these test case

Comment: ty @timdeschryver, I have updated the answer as ngrx Actions are required to be an object with the "type" property, as pointed out...

To fix your test, you can now use my answer

Answer (score 0):

var data = 'movies';
this.store.dispatch(data as any)

```js
var data = 'movies';
this.store.dispatch(data as any)
```

You can achieve the result by casting the string to any